# Erlang installation errors on Solaris 10

Tags: unix, erlang, rabbitmq, solaris, solaris-10

I am trying to install Erlang 17 on Solaris 10 (for RabbitMQ) following 
[this guide](http://erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html)

So when I run `./configure`

I see this message: `"ODBC library - link check failed"`

and this message: `"wxWidgets must be installed on your system."`

I tried to resolve this by following 
[these instructions](https://sites.google.com/site/comptekkia/erlang/how-to-install-erlang-on-ubuntu-10-10) as closely as I can. So I installed the following from OpenCSW:

- libncurses_dev
- unixodbc_dev
- libssl_dev

and I am still getting the same ODBC link check failed message. This looks like the same issue as: stackoverflow.com/questions/24471705

but I am having trouble fixing this on Solaris 10.

Any help is greatly appreciated; thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For my Centos 7, same problem with erlang 18.3 was solved with:

```
wget ftp://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.3.1611/os/x86_64/Packages/mesa-libGLU-9.0.0-4.el7.i686.rpm
yum install mesa-libGLU-9.0.0-4.el7.i686.rpm
yum install mesa-libGLU
```

**wx packeges:**

```
wget http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/wxGTK/2.8.12/8.el7/x86_64/wxBase-2.8.12-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i wxBase-2.8.12-8.el7.x86_64.rpm

wget http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/wxGTK/2.8.12/8.el7/x86_64/wxGTK-2.8.12-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i wxGTK-2.8.12-8.el7.x86_64.rpm

wget http://cbs.centos.org/kojifiles/packages/wxGTK/2.8.12/8.el7/x86_64/wxGTK-gl-2.8.12-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -i wxGTK-gl-2.8.12-8.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

UnixODBC

```
yum install unixODBC

yum install automake
yum install python-e*
yum install libSM
yum install SDL

yum install gcc gcc-c++ glibc-devel make ncurses-devel openssl-devel autoconf
yum install libyaml-devel
yum -y update
```

In your error, probably, showed what .so file is need, and find that .so with http://rpmfind.net/ for your OS

Or select version you whant with (eg libSM)

```
yum list libSM*
```

and intall it

```
yum install libSM-1.2.2-2.el7.i686
```